# How To Configure TLS Mutual Authentication for Azure Web App through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, ssl, client-certificates

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth) you can set ClientCertEnabled through the ARMClient Tool. You can nowadays also use https://resources.azure.com to do so or even set it as property in ARM Templates.

Is there any possibility to set it directly through Azure PowerShell? I found that retrieving an app through `Get-AzureRmWebApp` also states if ClientCertificates are enabled or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set it on the underlying resource. Sample:

```
$Resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceName $resourceName -ApiVersion 2016-08-01
$Resource.Properties.clientCertEnabled = "True"
$Resource | Set-AzureRmResource -Force
```

HTH